# How can I ignore everything but *.cpp files

Tags: git, github, gitignore

So I have a file directory that contains many types of files, but I would like to ignore every file except a few and any *.cpp. Here is what I have in my .gitignore, but the *.cpp is not being committed.

```
# Ignore Everything
*

# But not .cpp
!*.cpp
!.gitignore
!README.md
```

[image: File Directory]

Comment: Is this `.gitignore` file in the `src` directory, or is it the top level file? If it is the top level file, what happens when Git scans through the top level and finds an entity named `lab1` and looks in `.gitignore`: will `lab1` be ignored and hence not descended-into? (Or, if Git happens to get to looking into `lab1`, the same problem could occur at `src`.)

Comment: Well I am going to have multiple folders I want it to parse such as lab_2, etc. Is there a way for it to search every sub folder of the root?

Comment: I have written fairly extensively on this elsewhere, but *finding* it is a problem as there is so much fluff about Git and ignore files. Essentially, you have a choice: you can either limit yourself to specific directories (by putting `.gitignore` files into them, so that other directories don't have ignore rules here), or you can explicitly *un*-ignore directories. The latter cancels out all the speed improvement you get when Git can ignore a directory, but makes reasoning easier. You can also hybridize the two.

Comment: To un-ignore *all* directories, simply write `!*/` as a rule. `*/` matches a directory, and then the `!` means *don't ignore*, so Git will now look inside that directory, including all of its sub-directories (which also match `!*/`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "un-ignore" directories using `!*/` so that it tries adding that directory. But since `git` has no tracking for directories it will still have to find files to add. Your ignore all `*` and don't ignore cpp `!*.cpp` will do the trick

Modify your `.gitignore` to be:

```
# Ignore Everything
*

# But not .cpp
!*.cpp
# Or directories
!*/
!.gitignore
!README.md
```

The basic idea is `git` tracks files not directories.

Comment: *ignore directories using !\*/* Is it *ignore directories using \*/* or ***un**ignore directories using !\*/*?

Comment: @phd Hah, sorry about that.